# Sublime Text 3 plugin, Anaconda, doesn't work

Tags: plugins, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-anaconda

I've installed anaconda plugin using package control in sublime text 3, I've python 33 and anaconda installed separately and their path has been added to the PATH variable in MS Windows 7 (if matters). every plugin works fine except anaconda plugin which doesn't work at all! It has been install and I can see the user and default settings. But none of key bindings works. The lint capability is also doesn't work.

I've tried external path in the user setting via adding my anaconda installation path but it seems Sublime doesn't accept windows path such as :

`C:\Programs\Anaconda`

I've also tried re-installing but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 4):

This was a known issue already fixed in the last version. Just upgrade the plugin using Package Control.

Refer to https://github.com/DamnWidget/anaconda/issues/35 for more details

Comment: Yeap, the problem is solved.thanks, unfortunately I don't have enough reputation for a +1 ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It is an old question but I struggled a bit with it.

If you are using Windows executable, make sure to use slash after each backslash

> `C:\/Python34\/python.exe`

Without the slash, the anaconda will not take the executable's path into account

[image]